# Changing Classname throws Viewstate-Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, viewstate

I have to write a small application within an aspx-file on a foreign machine.

To have the right references etc. I took an aspx-page which is already working and only has a few differences to the wanted features.

So I copied the file and did my modifications. This all works well until I change the classname within the aspx. This works fine:

```
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>    
<%@ Page
        Language="C#"
        MasterPageFile="/_catalogs/masterpage/my.master"
        Debug="true"
        AutoEventWireup="true"
        ClassName="namespace.oldclassname"    
     %>
```

But changing the classname: (This is all what is left, no other lines in the file and still I get this error)

```
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
    <%@ Page
        Language="C#"
        MasterPageFile="/_catalogs/masterpage/my.master"
        Debug="true"
        AutoEventWireup="true"
        ClassName="namespace.newclassname"    
     %>
```

causes this error:

> Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a
>   Web Farm or cluster, ensure that  configuration specifies
>   the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot
>   be used in a cluster.

I found a lot of sources about this error, but none was class-specific. 
This page is hosted on a SharePoint-Environment but I would expect this is no SharePoint-specific issue.

Comment: have you verified the name in the .cs file and .designer.cs file? Often these are not changed automatically

Comment: There are no .cs - files. All code is done in the aspx-file (using <script>)

Comment: Why do you need to change ClassName property? You can remove it completely. MSDN states "A string that specifies the name of the page class that will be dynamically compiled when the page is requested. This value can be any valid class name and can include a fully qualified class name. If a value for this attribute is not specified, the class name for the compiled page is based on the page's file name and uses the default namespace ASP.". Why standard name convention does not fulfill your needs?

Comment: removing it causes the same exception